# What's the purpose of Installing ODAC while Oracle Server is already installed on the system

Tags: c++, .net, oracle, odac

I already installed Oracle Server on my System. It also installed the ODBC drivers. I also have `.net` and `c++` application that uses `ODBC` to connect to my database. My question is do I need to install ODBC on the same system where Oracle Server is already installed with the ODBC driver or no? What's the purpose of installing ODAC.

Answer (score 0):

ODAC isn't a product.  Instead, ODAC is a collection of drivers that provide Oracle client connectivity to Oracle.

If you are asked by the Oracle installer software to install a particular Oracle driver, (ODBC, OLE DB or a provider for .NET) then you just need to install whole the ODAC package.  ODAC consists of these tools:

The Oracle ODBC Driver

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Oracle Data Provider for .NET

Oracle Providers for ASP.NET Oracle Provider for OLE DB

Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server (MTS)